# Is it possible to use Eigen block expressions with templated parameters as lvalue?

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, eigen

I'm having problems with a function using the Eigen C++ library. It's a templated version of one of their examples but I can't seem to make it work in xcode.

```
template <typename Scalar>
void foo(){
  Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 2, 2> m = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 2, 2>::Identity();
  Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4> a = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar, 4, 4>::Constant(0.6);
  a.topLeftCorner<2,2>() = m; //Expected expression!
  std::cout << "result:" << std::endl << a << std::endl << std::endl;
  }
```

This code won't compile because of an "Expected Expression" error. I didn't actually call the function anywhere and it works fine if I don't template it and use double or float instead. Is there any reason it shouldn't work for the templated version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write

```
a.template topLeftCorner<2,2>() = m;
```

This is explained here: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicTemplateKeyword.html

Comment: Oops, by bad. I feel like downvoting myself.